# Show loader.gif when widgets load in php blog

Tags: widget, blogs, loading

Sometime if we embed widgets and when the DOM is fully loaded (showed by jquery's `$(document).ready()`
said it so), it still needs time for widgets to show (or load) from its servers (e.g. www.widgetbox.com). How to give a loader image for each widgets in that time lag? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the html, put a 'loading' image in place of the widget, then remove or hide the image when the widget is loaded.

The correct place to do this would be in the window load event.

```
window.onload = function () {
  // hide the 'loading' image
}
```

Comment: Yeah, very basic..But my question is when the code's been loaded, sometime the widget has not been showing yet. How to know when the widget has been showed while the code's been loaded far more earlier?

Comment: jquery .ready triggers when the code (DOM) is loaded, not when the widget is showed. There is time lag between them for a slow connection internet.

Comment: In that case you want use the windows load event. It fires after everything is rendered.